# Type of a React Styled Component with Custom Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, typescript-generics

Suppose that we have a styled component,

`const x = styled.div<{type?: string | undefined}>`, for example.

Without the props, we could use that the component has type `React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode}>`.

How can I strictly annotate the type when the styled component has custom props?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a compound component pattern for a form, such as:

```
type Form<T> = T & {
  Row: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }>;
};

const Form: Form<React.FC<{ type?: string | undefined }>> = styled.form<{
  type?: string | undefined;
}>`
 /* Styled using props */
`;

Form.defaultProps = {
  type: "regular",
};

const StyledFormRow = styled.div``;

const Row: React.FC<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => {
  return <StyledFormRow>{children}</StyledFormRow>;
};

Form.Row = Row;
```

However this gives the error

```
Type 'IStyledComponent<"web", Substitute<DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>, { type?: string | undefined; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Form<FC<{ type?: string | undefined; }>>'
```

However there is no such error if we don't add any custom props for the form, instead using

```
const Form: Form<React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }>> = styled.form`
  /* Styles that don't need custom props */
`;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this at all.

Comment: That's annoying, is there any reason for this or a nice way of refactoring to achieve the same thing?

Comment: No, there is no way to represent a type of a specific component with specific props.